# is it possible to perform a segue from tab bar item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I used a UIview controller for my app home page and then added a tab bar at the bottom just like Facebook and then added 3 more tab bar item, it doesn't let me perform a segue when  drag the tab bar item to a View Controller, is it possible progmatically or in storyboard?

Comment: I tried to drag my tab bar item to perform a segue to my other view controller but it doesn't let me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but i couldn't find a way to assign to a viewController its own viewControllers as in the TabViewController case.

**I solved it using containers.** One container for each tabBarItem in your tabBar, which are hidden or showed depending of the selected tabBarItem in the `tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` method.

**1.** Create your containers in your UIviewController in storyBoard: Just like this Select your tabBar and Ctrl+Drag to delegate the class for listen the tabBarDelegate methods: look here

**2.** Declare the corrisponging IBOutlets, incliding your tabBAr:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabsMainViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *directoryContainer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *groupsContainer;
@end
```

**3.** Select the container to show in the tabBarDelegate method:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

            switch (item.tag) {
            case 1:
                _directoryContainer.hidden = NO;
                _groupsContainer.hidden = YES;
             break;

            case 2:
                _directoryContainer.hidden = YES;
                _groupsContainer.hidden = NO;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Simple: You need a UITabViewController, tab bar items can't be used the way you're asking for.

Ctrl+drag from your tabview controller to a view you'd like to include (Third in this case)

You then select the **view controllers** option to add the relationship segue. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried it ctrl drag my tab bar item to the view controller I wanna make segue to but its doesn't let me and my home page is view controller where I added tab bar and then added tab bar item to the tab bar.

Comment: That's your issue, you need an actual tabBarController in there to handle those tabs:

Comment: But can you add more tab bar item on the tab bar

Comment: When I put a actual tabbarController, it doesn't let me put any other view object in it. Atlas myApp needs to have a home page where I display atlas a image if not anything else.

Comment: I don't think you're getting it. That controller isn't a view, you have views (First, second, third) that have the content you'd be switching to and from. Your first tab icon will be your "home page"  Good luck