# Tab bar without TabBarController - add View Controller for Tab bar item in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uistoryboard

I have added a Tab bar (not a TabViewController) to a View Controller and then added some Tab bar items to that Tab bar.

Now I want to attach other View Controllers to those tab bar items in Storyboard.

When I do Ctrl + Drag to View Controller from tab bar item I do not get any options.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278709/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-segue-from-tab-bar-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but i couldn't find a way to assign to a viewController its own viewControllers as in the TabViewController case.

**I solved it using containers.** One contarner for each tabBarItem in your tabBar, which are hidden or showed depending of the selected tabBarItem in the `tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` method.

**1.** Create your containers in your UIviewController in storyBoard:
[Just like  this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEaZa.png) Select your tabBar and Ctrl+Drag to delegate the class for listen the tabBarDelegate methods: [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQJkI.png)

**2.** Declare the corrisponging IBOutlets, incliding your tabBAr:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabsMainViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *directoryContainer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *groupsContainer;
@end
```

**3.** Select the container to show in the tabBarDelegate method:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

            switch (item.tag) {
            case 1:
                _directoryContainer.hidden = NO;
                _groupsContainer.hidden = YES;
             break;

            case 2:
                _directoryContainer.hidden = YES;
                _groupsContainer.hidden = NO;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I my self had thought to do it this way, when no other way is possible so did it this way.

Comment: The same happened to me, that's why it's better use a TabBarController. Nevertheless, I couldn't because I needed to put the taBBar at the top of the screen (instead of the bottom default position). And then, had to use containers.

Comment: I have 5 Tabs so added 5 Containers with 5 View Controllers. But what happens is, when my main View Controller (which has containers) is loaded all the Child VCs get loaded and their viewDidLoad method gets called. But when I switch to tab I want to perform some operation. How to do it?

Comment: Is there any way to load only one VC to memory at one time and replace it only when the tab is selected? By above method all 5 VC get loaded in memory at once.