# How to use a UITabBar without UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I want to implement a tab bar in the top of the iPhone screen, and want to be able to navigate in the different views. I have used the delegate method, here is how it looks in the storyboard:

[image: Click here to see the screenshot]

However, as I cannot delegate the TabBar to multiple containers, it seems the code that I have implemented doesn't work, here it is:

```
class PersonnesController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar : UITabBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var comptesContainer : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var membreContainer : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var discussionContainer : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tabBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBarDelegate(tabBar: UITabBar!, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

        switch item.tag {
            case 1:
                comptesContainer.isHidden = false
                membreContainer.isHidden = true
                discussionContainer.isHidden = true

            case 2:
                comptesContainer.isHidden = true
                membreContainer.isHidden = false
                discussionContainer.isHidden = true

            case 3:
                comptesContainer.isHidden = true
                membreContainer.isHidden = false
                discussionContainer.isHidden = true

            default:
                comptesContainer.isHidden = false
                membreContainer.isHidden = true
                discussionContainer.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

The real problem seems to be that I can only delegate the TabBar to only one container without being to delegate to the three. How could I achieve that?

PS : The best response I have found yet is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783074/tab-bar-without-tabbarcontroller-add-view-controller-for-tab-bar-item-in-story) but I fail to implement it, I don't know how he/she manages to delegate multiple times.

Comment: have you checked your constrains of tabbar?

Answer (score 0):

My question would be, why not using the UITabBarController? Just implementing the delegate will not do what you try to do, as long as noone is calling into the delegate (which is what the UITabBarController does/is for).

Comment: I already have a UITabBarController, and I want another TabBar at the top of the app, that is why I want to implement the UITabBar, which does not seem to be working. How do developers implement it ?

Comment: This isn't an answer. This should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but in my opinion you are on the wrong path here. That violates pretty much every user experience best practice for iOS. But let's say you have to: do you want to have the same tabs up there or completely different ones?

Comment: Ok I think I got what you try to do: PersonnesController itself is already in a tabbarcontroller and you add another tabbar for the PersonnesController right? Make sure that the tabbar's delegate in UIBuilder is set to the PersonnesController, do you get the events in your tabBarDelegate?

Comment: To your first response, I know that, but if you look in the messenger app for example, it has two tab bar's and it is pretty intuitive. So I don't think it is that much of a problem.
Concerning the delegation, I do understand the need for a modification of the delegation to the whole controller. However, nothing changes.. The answer of HMHero below does not work either. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the tabbar's delegate is set to the view contoller?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBar.delegate = self
}
```

Can you try this and see if the delegate fuction is being called?

Comment: I wrongly put the tabor's delegate to one of the containers, instead of one of the view controllers. Thank you.
I also added your peace of code, but I do not see the delegate function being called, should it appear in the debugger area? Where otherwise could I see it?

Comment: The problem is now that tabBarDelegate is never used or implemented, it seems like I function that has been written but that isn't used. 
I tried connecting it to the tabBar with a @IBAction, doesn't work..

Comment: I think you are confused. tabbar's delegate is PersonnesController and PersonnesController handles other sub containers.

Comment: Or PersonnesController should be a tab bar controller. Having UITabbar without UITabbarViewController doesn't give you much benefit except creating menus easily. Why don't you use three buttons instead of tabbar at the top if you are having hard time to make it work?